# Javascript select drop down menu onchange not firing properly

Tags: javascript, onchange

my onchange isn't firing the javascript method properly.

Select code (in HTML file)

```
<select id="crit_1" onchange="crit1Update()">
    <option value=null>Criteria 1</option>
 <option value="major">Major</option>
 <option value="grad">Graduation Year</option>
</select>
```

crit1Update() code (in external filter.js file in same folder as HTML file containing the above with the following code in head of HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filter.js">
</script>

function crit1Update() {
 var crit1 = document.criteria.getElementsByID("crit1");
 var criteria1 = crit1.options[crit1.selectedIndex].value;
 alert("criteria1"); // this is never firing, so this isnt getting called
 if (criteria1 == null) {
  // eventually set all other lists to null in here as well
  filter(null,null,null,null,null,null)
            // the above returns all the resumes 
            // (this is eventually going to filter resumes)
 }
 else if (criteria1 == "major") {
  alert("Major!");
 }
}
```

Are there any glaring or not glaring errors that I am missing? I dont see why the alert("criteria1" isnt being called. I come from a java background and this is my first foray into JS, so I may be missing something simple.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check on your typing.perhaps it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<select>` ID is "crit_1" and your function is looking for ID "crit1" (no underscore).

It would probably be a better idea to pass the `<select>` element as a reference to the function, eg

JavaScript

```
function crit1Update(crit1) {
    var criteria1 = crit1.options[crit1.selectedIndex].value;
```

HTML

```
<select id="crit1" name="crit1" onchange="crit1Update(this)">
```

Comment: @Ross: read some tutorial for the project that do you want to built up. so it can prevent the mistake during type the script.

Comment: @Klox, that is probably a good idea. I have been going back and forth between my js doc, html doc and www.w3schools.com

Comment: yah w3schools is a place for beginner like me too.keep trying and learning.;)

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in this method call:

```
document.criteria.getElementsByID(
```

should be

```
document.criteria.getElementById(
                            ^  ^ no "s" and lower case "d"
```

also make sure the id matches your HTML element e.g. "crit_1"

Comment: Good catch on the first typo, but you also missed the "s" - `getElementsByID` should be `getElementById`

Comment: thanks @Phil Brown I was so focused on the "D" I missed the s.